# Remove duplicate items from dropdownlist in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How can one remove duplicate items from dropdownlist in asp.net making sure that only unique values are listed in dropdownlist

Sorry if this is the duplicate question. Searched the SO but couldn't find it.

UPDATED CODE:

```
 private void BindDropdown(DropDownList ddlColumn)
    {
        DataTable dtBinddropDown = new DataTable();
        DataSet dsBinddrodown = new DataSet("dsSample");
        dtBinddropDown = (DataTable)Session[GlobalConstants.SESSION_MYSESSION];
        dsBinddrodown.Tables.Add(dtBinddropDown.Copy());
        System.Collections.ArrayList arItems = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        if (ddlColumn.ID == "ddlEntryDate")
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < dsBinddrodown.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                arItems.Add(dsBinddrodown.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column 1"].ToString());
            }
            ddlColumn.DataSource = arItems;
            ddlColumn.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the list? Is it from SQL? edit: If so, go with Pranay's answer.

Comment: I am getting from datatable-col-row-view

Comment: What is a "datatable-col-row-view"?

Comment: I mean i am using DataTable, datacolumn, data row, data view. I am not using SQL Datasource or i am not bringing the same from database

Comment: Question is updated with the code.

Comment: @Xor power - can I ask the obvious question as to why you're not doing `if(!arItems.Contains(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Col .."].ToString()) arItems.Add(...)` - would that not avoid duplicates? Please do let me know if I'm missing something, but you're manually adding your duplicate items - not much of a mystery here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your datasource uses a generic list, you could use LINQ to clear any duplicates before you bind it to your dropdown control - im assuming your using webforms ?

```
        // ******
        // Remove Any Duplicate Vehicles
        // ********************
        List<Vehicle> NoDuplicatesVehicleList = ListVehicle.AllVehicles;
        NoDuplicatesVehicleList = NoDuplicatesVehicleList.GroupBy(x => x.VehicleID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

this is what i have used to remove duplicate vehicle objects on my site using the VehicleID, but the same would apply to your dropdown.

hope that helps

Truegilly

Answer (score 2):

I agree w/ Pranay's answer, but in the somewhat rare case that you don't have access to the db/sproc with the query, here's a c# based approach:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string itemName = Convert.ToString(row["colname"]);
        if (dt.Select(String.Format("Colname='{0}'", itemName)).Count() > 1)
            row.Delete();
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`DataView.ToTable Method (Boolean, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx)

```
DataTable newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true,"{your column name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linq. here is an example

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;


ArrayList inputList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList outputList = new ArrayList();
inputList.Add(1);
inputList.Add(2);
inputList.Add(3);
inputList.Add(1);

inputList.ToArray().Distinct().ToList()
            .ForEach(a => outputList.Add(a));
```